# How to docker image of spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I'm facing several issues in creating docker application in windows environment.

Can someone help me with a link or reference or steps on how to create docker image for spring boot application in windows environment?

Basically the application runs perfectly fine in IntelliJ or Eclipse STS without any issues (Zero Issues)

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: These might help https://www.baeldung.com/dockerizing-spring-boot-application and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-docker-images.

Comment: Follow steps from https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/.   Start from `Containerize It` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:(https://github.com/briansjavablog/build-and-run-spring-boot-with-docker)

The code of the main class is shown below, and nothing else is added. Next I will use the default actuator health endpoint to test the application.

```
package com.blog.samples.docker;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}  
}
```

The following content is the image file defined in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
MAINTAINER Brian Hannaway
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn package
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/docker-boot-intro-0.1.0.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "docker-boot-intro-0.1.0.jar"]
```

`FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD` tells Docker to use the Maven compiler.

`maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine` builds the basic image used in the first step. Docker will first find the image locally. If it does not exist locally, it will be pulled from DockerHub. Maven will be removed in the final stage (introduced by the subsequent COPY command). Considering the reasons for fast downloading and image size control, the Alpine version of Maven image is selected.

`MAINTAINER Brian Hannaway` is optional, but providing a touch point for image authors can improve maintainability. (The point of application verification in this experiment)

`COPY pom.xml /build/` Create a build directory in the mirror and copy the pom.xml file.

`COPY src /build/src/` Copy into the src directory to the build directory in the mirror.

WORKDIR /build/ sets build as the working directory. Any subsequent commands are run in this directory.

RUN mvn package executes the mvn package to run the compiled and packaged application, and generates an executable JAR file. When building a mirror for the first time, Maven will pull all the required dependencies from the public Maven repository and cache them locally on the mirror. Subsequent builds will use this cached version of the mirroring layer, which means that dependencies will be referenced locally without having to pull them from the outside again.
At this point, the image definition has been completed, just wait for it to be built into an executable JAR file. This is the first part of a multi-stage construction. The next stage will get the JAR and run it.

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine tells Docker that the next step of the multi-stage build uses the basic image of openjdk:8-jre-alpine. Using the Alpine version of Java 8 JRE again, the choice of this step is actually more important than the previous Maven version selection, because the image in the final version is only openjdk:8-jre-alpine, so if you want to control the final image size as much as possible , It is very important to choose a lightweight JRE mirror.

WORKDIR /app tells Docker to create another /app working directory in the image, and any subsequent commands will run in this directory.

COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/docker-boot-intro-0.1.0.jar /app/ tells Docker to copy ocker-boot-intro-0.1.0.jar from the /build/target directory in the MAVEN_BUILD stage to / app directory.

As mentioned earlier, the advantage of multi-stage construction is that it allows users to copy specific content from one construction stage to another, and discard all other content. If you need to keep everything from the MAVEN_BUILD stage, the final image will contain Maven (including Maven local libraries) tools and all class files generated in the target directory. By selecting the necessary content from the MAVEN_BUILD stage, the resulting image will be much smaller.

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"] tells Docker which commands to run when the container runs this image. This part uses colons to isolate multiple commands. In this case, you need to copy the execution JAR file to the /app directory to run.

After completing the Docker image definition, you can start building. Open the directory containing the Dockerfile (root directory). Run the following command to build the image:

```
docker image build -t docker-boot-intro
```

The -t parameter is the specified name and optional label. If you don't specify a label, Docker will automatically mark it as the latest.

```
$ docker image build -t docker-boot-intro .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  26.56MB
Step 1/10 : FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
---> 293423a981a7
Step 2/10 : MAINTAINER Brian Hannaway
---> Using cache
---> db354a426bfd
Step 3/10 : COPY pom.xml /build/
---> Using cache
---> 256340699bc3
Step 4/10 : COPY src /build/src/
---> Using cache
---> 65eb0f98bb79
Step 5/10 : WORKDIR /build/
---> Using cache
---> b16b294b6b74
Step 6/10 : RUN mvn package
---> Using cache
---> c48659e0197e
Step 7/10 : FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
---> f7a292bbb70c
Step 8/10 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> 1723d5b9c22f
Step 9/10 : COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/docker-boot-intro-0.1.0.jar /app/
---> Using cache
---> d0e2f8fbe5c9
Step 10/10 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "docker-boot-intro-0.1.0.jar"]
---> Using cache
---> f265acb14147
Successfully built f265acb14147
Successfully tagged docker-boot-intro:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
Brians Computer@DESKTOP-077OUJ8 MINGW64 /c/dev/docker-boot-intro (master)
```

When running the build, Docker will execute each command in the Docker file one by one. Create a layer with a unique ID for each step. For example, the ID of the layer created in step 1 is 293423a981a7.

When building an image for the first time, Docker will fetch any external images it needs from DockerHub, and then start building new layers on top of it. This will make the first build very slow.

During the build process, Docker checks the cache before attempting to build the layer to see if there is already a cached version of the build layer. If a cached version of the layer is available, Docker will use it directly instead of building it from scratch. This means that once an image layer is built, subsequent builds are reused, which will be much faster. You can see that the cache layer is used through the hash value of the Docker cache output in the above build output. Take what happened in step 6 above as an example:

As part of the RUN mvn package command, Docker will fetch all the POM dependencies from the public Maven repository, build it into an executable JAR, and store all of them in the layer with ID c48659e0197e. The next time this image is built, Maven dependencies and application JARs will be taken out of the cache layer without having to download and build again.

Comment: After the image is built, you can run a container with the following command:



docker container run -p 8080:8080 docker-boot-intro

Comment: Will not maven would be a dependency.....What would happen when Maven is not installed and the docker image is started to run

Comment: I'm bit confused with bundling - whether to bundle with all installations..How maven or java installation is also been bundled. Do we bundle or not in Docker is a question which comes to the mind always...